# How to get this PHP while statement to terminate?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
$pdo2 = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbname', $username, $password);
$pdo2->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth2 = $pdo2->prepare('
    SELECT info, date
      FROM Comment, Professor_Comment
     WHERE pID = ?
     AND Comment.commID = Professor_Comment.commID;
');
$sth2->execute(array(
    $pID2
));

                // Did we get any *comments*
                while($sth2->rowCount() > 0) {
                $row2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        echo "<h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>
                        <span> Comment {$row2['info']} </span><br>
                        <span> Comment {$row2['date']} </span><br>
                        "; // end echo
                }
                unset($sth2);
                ?>
```

How do I get this while statement to terminate once all records in the given query above are retrieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `while` statement to

```
while($row2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>
    <span> Comment {$row2['info']} </span><br>
    <span> Comment {$row2['date']} </span><br>
    "; // end echo
}
```

The while statement will execute as long as `$sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` returns a usable value and will assign said value to the `$row2` variable.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for working with my code and showing me why it works. A+ haha.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` returns false when it runs out of rows to fetch. So check the return value from `fetch`:

```
while ($row2 = $sth2->fetch(POD::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while($row2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
  echo .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Did we get any *comments*
$rowCount = $sth2->rowCount();
while($rowCount--) {
$row2 = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  echo "<h2 style='margin:0; padding:0;'>Recent Comments</h2>
  <span> Comment {$row2['info']} </span><br>
  <span> Comment {$row2['date']} </span><br>
  "; // end echo
}
unset($sth2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so

```
while ($row = $sth2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    ...
}
```

`rowCount()` always returns an integer bigger than or equal to 0.